# Summarize into a placeholder category and drill through for details

Tags: powerbi

I am new to power bi, run into a situation that I want combine certain items into a collective category showing in a summary visual but be able to drill through for details.  example... I have a list of fruits, instead of showing everything crowding the visual, I want to summarize a few showing as "Tropical fruit".  And I want to be able to drill through to see the actual breakdown data of the lychee, dragon fruit and pineapple etc.....   How can I do this without messing the original data in the table?  Appreciate knowledge sharing, thanks,
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlwcD.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add New CalculatedColumn in DAX:

```
Labels = 
var __fruit = Fruit[Fruit]
return
SWITCH( TRUE(),
__fruit in { "Pineapple","Mango","DragonFruit", "lychee" } , "Tropical fruit",
__fruit
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but this is just a small example, for my case there will be some 20-30 items that need to be grouped under the tropical fruit category, it would be troublesome to manage that list which may change from time to time. What if i put this tropical fruit subset in another table, can the DAX formula be adjusted to take from there, not sure if i am making any sense. Thanks

Comment: if you have table with name then replace:

__fruit in { "Pineapple","Mango","DragonFruit", "lychee" } 

to 

__fruit in VALUES(MyFruitList[Tropical])

Comment: thanks, its working and producing the output I wanted :)